# How to show two topologies are the same?

Tags: general-topology

I am new to topology, and have been given an assignment to show that two topologies, on the same set, are the same (respectively). So far, in my class, we have only discussed metric spaces, topological spaces and basis for a topology (merely definitions).
The assignment goes: Suppose $\eta: \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous (with respect to the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$) function such that for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, the following three conditions are satisfied:

1. $\eta(x)=0 \Longleftrightarrow x=0$
2. if $y\geq x$, then $\eta(y)\geq \eta(x)$
3. $\eta(x+y)\leq \eta(x)+\eta(y)$

Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space and define $d': X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ by $d'(x,y)=\eta(d(x,y))$. Show that: the topologies on $X$, defined by $d$ and $d'$, respectively, are the same. 
I have already shown that $d'$ is a metric. My problem here is that I really don't know how to get started. Can somebody give me a hint?

Comment: The function $\eta$ is obviously not defined on $X \times X$, rather on $\mathbb{R}$, isn't it ?

Comment: You may show that the identity map is bi-continuous between the two spaces.

Comment: oh yes, my bad!!! the fuction $\eta$ goes from $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ to $\mathbb{R}$...

Answer (score 2):

Let $O$ be a $d$-open set. You have to show it is also $d'$-open. So let $x \in O$ be arbitrary. As $O$ is given to be $d$-open, there is some $r>0$ such that $B_d(x,r) \subseteq O$.

We have to find $r'>0$ such that $B_{d'}(x,r') = \{y \in X\mid d'(x,y) = \eta(d(x,y)) < r'\} \subseteq O$ as well. Can you use properties of $\eta$ to achieve this?

Then you have to do the converse as well: show that a $d'$-open set is $d$-open too. After that you'll be done.

Answer (score 0):

Pick an open set for the topology defined by $d$ and show it is also an open set for $d'$. And then conversely.

Hint: For this remember what is a basis for the topology defined by a metric and choose such a particular open set $O$ (how does it relate to $d$ ?). Now consider a point $x \in O$, it remains to show that there is an $O'$, an open set for $d'$, such that $x\in O' \subset O$.